# Error when testing Connection of Global Element in MuleStudio

Tags: mule, mule-studio, throwable

I'm using MuleStudio 3.4 and have a simple Flow with a Drupal Connector. The Configuration for this Drupal Connector comes from a Global ElemCent Configuration.

But when i want to test the connection from the Global Elements Properties Window, i get the the message:

Test Connection failed: Invalid Global Element. Cannot access the Global Element to test.
java.long.Throwable

Here is the Configuration XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:drupal="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/drupal" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/drupal http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/drupal/1.0/mule-drupal.xsd">

<drupal:config name="Drupal" username="dba" password="***" apiUrl="/service/rest/" server="localhost" port="8888" commentEndpoint="comment" fileEndpoint="file" nodeEndpoint="node" userEndpoint="user" doc:name="Drupal" taxonomyTermEndpoint="taxonomy-term" taxonomyVocabularyEndpoint="taxonomy-vocabulary">
    <drupal:connection-pooling-profile initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_ONE" exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW"/>
</drupal:config>
<flow name="drupal-esbFlow1" doc:name="drupal-esbFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="drupal/node/create" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <drupal:create-node config-ref="Drupal" username="dba" password="***" doc:name="Drupal">
        <drupal:node type="article" title="[message.payload['title']]">
            <drupal:body>
                <drupal:und ref="#[payload]"/>
            </drupal:body>
        </drupal:node>
    </drupal:create-node>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Add the configuration code to the post. That will help in providing solution.

Comment: Are you using placeholders for either your username or your password?

Comment: what do you mean with placeholders? i have defined username and password in my Global Elements Config.

Comment: By placeholders I mean resolving your username/password with ${your_credentials} as opposed to use the actual value directly in the connector configuration

Comment: I have written the value of username/password directly in the global elements configuration. How do i resolve my username/password with ${my_credentials} ?

Comment: If I disable "Session authentication" in Drupals REST Server Service Configuration (then all stuff is done by an anonymous user), i can create nodes and do all actions i want. So iam assuming its something with Session Vars, because Mule doesnt take care of them? any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

just make sure that you are persisting this information in `mule-app.properties`. Otherwise you can create another property place holder and after referencing that you can go ahead and use.